# A field or property with the name 'ProductName' was not found on the selected data source

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to update a row in a gridview and I get an error like this: 
A field or property with the name 'ProductName' was not found on the selected data source.

I am using the Northwind database.

This is my code:

```
protected void gvProducts_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE Products SET ProductName = @ProductName WHERE ProductID =@ ProductID";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", Convert.ToInt32(gvProducts.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["ProductID"]));
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)gvProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0];
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", tb.Text);
    int effect = 0;
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        effect = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
        gvProducts.EditIndex = -1;
        gvProducts.DataBind();
    }
    if (effect != 0)
        fillDetailed();
}
```

the database scheme is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products] (
[ProductID]       INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[ProductName]     NVARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
[SupplierID]      INT           NULL,
[CategoryID]      INT           NULL,
[QuantityPerUnit] NVARCHAR (20) NULL,
[UnitPrice]       MONEY         CONSTRAINT [DF_Products_UnitPrice] DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
[UnitsInStock]    SMALLINT      CONSTRAINT [DF_Products_UnitsInStock] DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
[UnitsOnOrder]    SMALLINT      CONSTRAINT [DF_Products_UnitsOnOrder] DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
[ReorderLevel]    SMALLINT      CONSTRAINT [DF_Products_ReorderLevel] DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
[Discontinued]    BIT           CONSTRAINT [DF_Products_Discontinued] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Products] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProductID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Products_Categories] FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Categories] ([CategoryID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Products_Suppliers] FOREIGN KEY ([SupplierID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Suppliers] ([SupplierID]),
CONSTRAINT [CK_Products_UnitPrice] CHECK ([UnitPrice]>=(0)),
CONSTRAINT [CK_ReorderLevel] CHECK ([ReorderLevel]>=(0)),
CONSTRAINT [CK_UnitsInStock] CHECK ([UnitsInStock]>=(0)),
CONSTRAINT [CK_UnitsOnOrder] CHECK ([UnitsOnOrder]>=(0))
```

);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [CategoriesProducts]
    ON [dbo].[Products]([CategoryID] ASC);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [CategoryID]
    ON [dbo].[Products]([CategoryID] ASC);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ProductName]
    ON [dbo].[Products]([ProductName] ASC);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [SupplierID]
    ON [dbo].[Products]([SupplierID] ASC);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [SuppliersProducts]
    ON [dbo].[Products]([SupplierID] ASC);

[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8tAF.png)

This is the .aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvProducts_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="gvProducts_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvProducts_RowUpdating">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Производ" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="Единечна цена" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Количина" />
            <asp:CommandField CancelText="Откажи" EditText="Уреди" ShowEditButton="True" UpdateText="Промени" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: do you have a column named `ProductName`?

Comment: Yes, there is such a column in the Northwind database

Comment: Ca you post the schema for `products` table?

Comment: What are the exact details of the exception?

Comment: I just addes an image of the exception I am getting.

Comment: I don't think it is a problem with the query but a problem in FillDetailed(). That doesn't sound like a SQL exception it sounds like you are trying to set  ProductName property on a class that doesn't have it.

Comment: Share the .aspx file with GridView.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of Data Source are you using? Object data source/Sql data source? Please check if the table definition has been changed after creating the data source and the data source is not refreshed. In that case the updated columns in table definition will not be reflected and am exception like this can happen.